# EventListener for a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, addeventlistener

I have an EventListener that references an Id and it works well, the only problem is that i have at least a dozen places where this EventListener needs to reference so i dont want to have a dozen scripts that are all the same but have a different Id. Is therea way to have the EventListener that references a class that i could use in all the places i need it.
Thanks

JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.getElementById("chartJump").addEventListener("click", function (e) { e.preventDefault() });
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuGraphOne">
    <!--DROPDOWN MENU-->
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="chartJumpOne" href="#graphOneChart">Chart</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="tableJumpOne" href="#graphOneData">Data</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using classes. Every element should have a common class. And with jQuery you can do this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".className").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Get more info about [`$.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`$.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). As you have added [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I have given the jQuery solution.

Using vanilla JavaScript, you can achieve the same functionality in two ways:

**For old browsers:**

```
window.onload = function () {
  list = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
};
```

**For new browsers:**

```
window.onload = function () {
  list = document.querySelectorAll(".className");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Don't forget to add links to documentation ;)

Comment: i don't know if i'm doing something wrong but the page is still "jumping" when i used this code (what the event listener prevents)

Comment: The jQuery answer wasn't working for me but i used the new browser javascript. Thanks!

Comment: @PraveenKumar [`querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) has better browser support than [`getElementsByClassName`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname). Although I would suggest that `getElementsByClassName` is _probably_ the better to use, considering he is only matching classes.

Comment: @JamieBarker I didn't know that! But is `querySelectorAll` supported in old IE < 8 and browsers?

Comment: @PraveenKumar If you click the "Show All" button on that page, you will see that unfortunately they are not. No surprises there, but these days nobody cares about 8, let alone 7

Comment: You don't know how corporates still consider IE 6 a modern browser!

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using `jQuery` you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".chartJump");


for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {

    els[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        eventHandler();
    });
};
```

If you've `jQuery` you can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(".chartJump").on('click', function () {
    // Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to jQuery library in your script, then why use raw JS code, which is so difficult to write.

First of all add a class name for all your elements, then use the same class selector for attaching a event listener like `click` to it

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuGraphOne">
<!--DROPDOWN MENU-->
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class='jumpChart' href="#graphOneChart">Chart</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class='jumpChart' href="#graphOneData">Data</a></li>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$('.jumpChart').on('click',function(){
    //handle the event here
});
```

For more info refer to jQuery forum: http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a class to each of these elements and use a for loop to iterate through and place a eventListener.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.className');

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {

  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    // Do something amazing

  });

}
```

via: http://pencilscoop.com/2014/06/using-eventlisteners-on-multiple-elements

or you could just add onclick to your elements individually

```
 <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#graphOneChart" onclick="function1()">Chart</a>
```