# Slick Slider, click full slide to go to URL without HTML markup or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, onclick, slick.js

So I'm trying to "hack" Slick Slider on our website because the developers of our CMS platform did not put in the ability to allow the whole slide to be clickable. Instead, they only by default allow buttons and links to be added to slides. Since that will not work for our first slide we are trying to display, I'm trying to make the whole slide, when clicked, go to a URL.

The caveat is that I can't have any HTML markup (no onclick in the HTML) since I have no access to directly edit the HTML.

Also, I can't use jQuery because adding the script (any version) breaks the slider, probably due to some conflicting code with Slick slider.

I tried this ("rewards" is the class name of the first slide that I want to make clickable):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByClassName("rewards").onclick = function() {
    window.location = "https://www.citrustowncenter.com/rewards-program/";
  };
</script>
```

But it does not work. I just want to target the first slide with class name "rewards".

Here is the test page: https://www.citrustowncenter.com/testing-2

So is there any raw JS solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you try it with `mouseup` rather thank click?

Comment: Nothing happens (still not clickable). =3
I tried:  
`<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByClassName("rewards").mouseup = function () {window.location = "https://www.citrustowncenter.com/rewards-program/";};
</script>`

Comment: The example at the top of your test page seems to be working for me.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up getting it to work with a solution I found in this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939470/eventlistener-for-a-class/30939635) .

Comment: This is the exact code I used: 
`window.onload = function () {
    list = document.querySelectorAll(".className");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      list[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
};`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EventListener for a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939470/eventlistener-for-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I ended up getting it to work with a solution I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939470/eventlistener-for-a-class/30939635):

```
window.onload = function () {
  list = document.querySelectorAll(".className");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
};
```